# Issue with ScrollTop function - Over scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am experiencing an issue with my WordPress site - it uses a ScrollTop function to scroll to each section break. What I am experiencing is that when scrolling, it doesn't scroll to the right location.

I've look all over the code, and can't determine what is causing the issue. You can see the basic code below for ScrollTop, nothing too different.

```
 var hash = this.hash;

   // animate
   jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
       scrollTop: jQuery(this.hash).offset().top,

     }, 1000, 'swing', function(){

       // when done, add hash to url
       // (default click behaviour)
       window.location.hash = hash;
     });
```

I've attempted offsetting the scroll, but each section seems to have different overscroll.

I've removed all CSS padding and margins which hasn't changed the issue. Has anyone experienced a similar issue with scrolling before?

The strange aspect is, that if you click the same link again, it figures it out and scrolls to the right section ID.

You can find a link to my website [here](http://kayleighandtom.co.uk).

I've currently got an issue with FadeIn which I'm working on, so ignore that part of it.

Would it be a good assumption that the scroll and fadeIn are conflicting each other? The FadeIn on some sections does in fact increase the length of the Div.

Comment: Thanks Henri, I'll give that a go and get back to you. Good to have someone confirm my suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fadeIn is probably the reason since it changes heights of the elements. You could avoid this by applying fadeIn animations for the divs that are above the selected section before you manipulate the scrollTop.